# pagination query for postgres and nodejs server

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, pagination, get

I am trying to get all the users from my databse by defing the query using orderby and odertype then limit and offset.But while writing the query as given i have used paramertrized form for it is not returning any results.the error that is encountered was there is problem near $1 And$2.

```
const getPagination = (page, size) => {
    const limit = size ? +size : 4;
    const offset = page ? page * limit : 0;
    return { limit, offset };
  };

var getUsers =async(req,res)=>{

let orderby = req.query.orderby
    ? req.query.orderby
    : "user_id";
    console.log(orderby)
  
let orderDir = req.query.orderDir
    ? req.query.orderDir
    : "DESC";
const { page, size } = req.query;
const { limit, offset } = getPagination(page, size);
const query='SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $1 $2 LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4'
await db.query(query,[orderBy,orderDir,limit,offset])
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        res.json(data.rows);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving users."
        });
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable reason why you're getting an error is because the orderBy/orderDir are passed as strings into the query instead of as raw sql. This will give queries such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
ORDER BY 'colName' 'ASC'
```

Where the order by is now a constant string thus the entries are not ordered at all and the quotes around the direction will indeed throw an error.

Inserting the direction into the query can probably best be done by replacing $2 in the query with something like ${lower(orderDir) === 'asc' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'} and replacing the the 's of the query string with `s.

For the column to order by it's probably best if you define which values orderBy can take, check if the correct input is given and then use an if statement to create a string to insert into the query instead. As long as the string being inserted is created in your code rather than being unsanitized user input there is no risk of sql injection and the query should work as intended.